# Question about a weird Java regex behavior

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a regex that could match the leading digits and . in a String. But it seems just not working correctly. The regex I'm using is

```
"^[\\.\\d]+"
```

Below is my code:

```
public void testMiscellaneous() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~testMiscellaneous~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    String s1 = ".123 *[DP7_Dog]";
    String s2 = ".123";
    String s3 = "1.12.3";
    String s4 = "a1.12.3";
    final String numberRegex = "^[\\.\\d]+";
    System.out.println(s1.matches(numberRegex));
    System.out.println(s2.matches(numberRegex));
    System.out.println(s3.matches(numberRegex));
    System.out.println(s4.matches(numberRegex));
}
```

The outputs are

```
false
true
true
false
```

However, I would expect true, true, true, false. There must be something wrong with the regex, but I can't find it. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't cause the match to fail (see Carl's answer for that), but you don't have to escape the dot inside a character class. `"[.\\d]"` is enough (as a Java string).

Comment: Thanks, Tim. It works without the double escapes. When you say "a character class", is it the same as character set defined inside brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `matches()` insists on matching your entire input String, as if there was a `^` at the beginning of your regexp and `$` at the end.

You may be better off using `Matcher.find()` or `Matcher.lookingAt()`, or (if you want to be dumb and lazy like myself) simply tacking `.*` on the end of your pattern.

Comment: Carl, thanks a lot for your answer. I append the .* at the end of regex, and it works. 

It confuses me because the split() method matches part of the input string. So, if I use the same regex in split() as used in matches(), it would give me an empty String[].

Thanks again for your instant help.